# ParseReact realtime like Firebase and MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, reactjs

I started using ParseReact (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseReact), but i want to know if there are any way of realtime data ? Like in MeteorJS or Firebase.

---

To add Parse data to a component, it simply needs to subscribe to a standard Parse Query. This is done through an implementation of the newly-proposed observe() API for React. The ParseReact Mixin allows a version of this new lifecycle method to be used today with Parse Queries.

If you're using React with ES6 classes, we also provide a subclass of React.Component that allows you to use the observe() and Query-specific APIs.

```
var CommentBlock = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ParseReact.Mixin], // Enable query subscriptions

  observe: function() {
    // Subscribe to all Comment objects, ordered by creation date
    // The results will be available at this.data.comments
    return {
      comments: (new Parse.Query('Comment')).ascending('createdAt')
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    // Render the text of each comment as a list item
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.data.comments.map(function(c) {
          return <li>{c.text}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

Whenever this component mounts, it will issue the query and the results will be attached to this.data.comments. Each time the query is re-issued, or objects are modified locally that match the query, it will update itself to reflect these changes.

Mutations are dispatched in the manner of Flux Actions, allowing updates to be synchronized between many different components without requiring views to talk to each other. All of the standard Parse data mutations are supported, and you can read more about them in the Data Mutation guide.

```
// Create a new Comment object with some initial data
ParseReact.Mutation.Create('Comment', {
  text: 'Parse <3 React'
}).dispatch();
```

---

I tried the example, **but always have to reload view**. It`s not the same as Firebase and MeteorJS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also like to hear more about this...Not sure if this is actually a supported feature or not. As the documentation states, Queries you are subscribed to in the `observe` function will be updated with new props/state, as well as any time a Mutation occurs. In this sense it is very much like Meteor in that changes changes to state (much like changes to Session variables) can reload queries to the backend.

Where it differs is that, unlike Meteor, changes in Parse (say, directly in the db or from another front-end instance) are not communicated to all subscribed React front-ends. At least as far as I can tell. Which is kinda disappointing. Would love to hear from someone more experienced, who *hasn't* just been messing with ParseReact for the past 24 hours.